# jQuery form post converts boolean checkboxes to "on" and "off"?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a fairly simple form with a checkbox, and I noticed that my checkbox values weren't being picked up on my server side app:

```
$.post('CreateForm', $('#new-form').serialize(), ...
```

Everything else posts correctly, but I'm seeing in Firebug that it'll serialize the checkbox value as "on" or "off" instead of "true" and "false" that I get with a normal `<form method="post" action="formpage">` ... what's going on here, is this expected behavior? My server side model binder doesn't equate "on" with "true" and thus drops the value. Obviously I could change the model binder, but wanted to make sure I wasn't doing it wrong.

Edit:

Here's my markup:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="CheckboxValue" >
```

jQuery version 1.4.4

In Firebug here's the resulting post:

```
... other variables &CheckboxValue=on
```

Comment: A checkbox is serialized using its name and value.  Check the name and value attributes of your checkboxes.

Answer (score 71, accepted):

The problem is that your checkboxes do not have `value` attributes.  When jQuery serializes the form, it uses 'on' as the default value.

You should give your checkbox a value:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="CheckboxValue" value="true" />
```

See example here: http://jsfiddle.net/U6Sbw/1/

Comment: Why does jQuery do that?  Surely 'true' would be a better default?

Answer (score 11):

A little late, but just in case someone stumbles across this: if you also want **false** values to be output, this jQuery plugin provides the option to always ignore the checkbox's "value" and instead serialize it as "true" or "false":

http://tdanemar.wordpress.com/2010/08/24/jquery-serialize-method-and-checkboxes/

Comment: I am glad @Tao add this here, helps me to sort out my issue

Comment: Thank you very much, exactly what I was looking for. This solution also allows you to substitute any string literal into the final expressions of the `return`'s ternary operator if desired.

Answer (score 7):

Here is what i did which seems to work great.  Am using js2form to marshall to sping mvc/jackson controller.

Have a function I run with the following:

```
$('input[type=checkbox]').unbind('click.checks').bind('click.checks', function(e){
    $(this).val($(this).is(':checked'));
});
```